# Functions are not valid as a react child? - Need help to extract fetched data into table

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

Quick summary of my homework-project.

I have a REST API on my backend, which has a API method returning the Star Wars characters from an external API.

In my web Development, I am trying to fetch these data from my REST API, and I can see the data is actually shown in the browser developer tools, but I get another error.

"Warning: index.js:1437 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Can you please see what's going wrong in below .js file?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Table,} from 'react-bootstrap'

const urlCharacters = 'URL WORKS - BUT NOT SHOWING HERE.';

class Characters extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {characters: []}
    ;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
      //async fetchCharactersFromBackend(){
        const res = await fetch(urlCharacters);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        const newData = data.map(e => JSON.parse(e.name));
        this.setState([newData]);
        }

render() {
  if (!this.state.characters) {
      return null
    }
  return (
    <div>
    <h2>Persons table</h2>
    <Table striped bordered hover>

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Character Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.renderCharacters}
      </tbody>
      </Table>;

      </div>
  );
}
    renderCharacters(characters) {
      characters.forEach(e => {
        return ("<tr><td>" + e.name + "</td></tr>")
      });
    }
    }

  /*
  Persons = () => {
  return (
   <div>
  <h2>Persons table</h2>
  <Table striped bordered hover>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Character Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.renderCharacters}
    </tbody>
    </Table>;

    </div>
  );
};
*/





export default Characters;
```

Comment: this.setState({characters: [newData]})

Comment: Also this.setState([newData]) should be this.setState({ characters: newData }) probably.

Comment: Also you may not need JSON.parse() depending on your API which may already be providing parsed JSON. You can probably omit that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following fixes and let me know if it works:

```
this.setState([newData]);  --> this.setState({characters: newData})

{this.renderCharacters} --> {this.renderCharacters()}
```

update the renderCharacters to the following:

```
    renderCharacters() {
        return this.state.characters.map(e => {
          return ("<tr><td>" + e.name + "</td></tr>")
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you they really need { characters: [newData] }? That would create a nested array for the state property, [[{}]]. Should really just be { characters: newData } probably.

Comment: I did the following changes.

The data still appears in the developer tools console, but now I get this error below; 

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
... on line 
        const newData = data.map(e => JSON.parse(e.name));

Comment: Also remove the if condition in render its of no use

Comment: I just marked the answer. Now I get data, but not correctly. Data looks like below in a single row..

<tr><td>Luke Skywalker</td></tr><tr><td>C-3PO</td></tr><tr><td>R2-D2</td></tr><tr><td>Darth Vader</td></tr><tr><td>Leia Organa</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

`{this.renderCharacters}`

should be

`{this.renderCharacters()}`